# Pass Angularjs expression/variable to asp.net mvc action link as Route Parameter

Tags: c#, angularjs, asp.net-mvc

How can we pass angularjs expression/ varibale to asp.net mvc actionlink ?

Here is my asp.net mvc actionlink code

```
 @Html.ActionLink("{{row.x}}", "Details", "Info", new { id = "{{row.x}}" }, null)
```

In the first parameter {{row.x}} works fine as it displays value but when being passed as route parameter it retains itself as {{row.x}} and does not evaulate.If i remove quotes it doesnt compile.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Razor code executes at the server. So you cannot pass your client side angular variable as the route value dictionary parameter for the `Html.ActionLink` helper method.

What you can do is build the html markup for the link with pure html and append angular data in the `href` value as needed. You can still use `Url.Action` helper method to build the correct relative url to the Info action method.

```
<a href="@Url.Action("Info","Details")?id={{row.x}}">{{row.x}}</a>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `ng-href` and `Url.Content` as following

```
<a ng-href="@Url.Content("~/Info/Details/")?id={{row.x}}">{{row.x}}</a>
```