# Passing Data from Angular to Razor (MVC5)

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

I created a project in MVC5 over Entity Framework and AngularJS.
Now, what I want is to pass every database object to an MVC controller, in order to update their values. (ex: to modify a "customer" value)
The following code doesn't work..

```
 <table class="table">                
                    <tr ng-repeat="r in customers">
                        <td>{{r.ID}}</td>
                        <td>{{r.LastName}}</td>
                        <td>{{r.FirstName}}</td>
                        <td>{{r.Phone}}</td>
                        <td>{{r.Email}}</td>
                        <td><a href="@Url.Action("Edit","Edit")?id={{r.ID}}"></a></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
```

Please help me about how to pass r.ID to the razor above

```
@Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = r.ID })
```

Comment: refer [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34979126/pass-angularjs-expression-variable-to-asp-net-mvc-action-link-as-route-parameter),[this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25182830/html-actionlink-and-angularjs-value),[this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/316889/asp-net-mvc-passing-an-id-in-an-actionlink-to-the-controller)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need put ng- before href:

```
<a ng-href="@Url.Action("Edit","Edit")?id={{r.ID}}"></a>
```

Also `ng-src` for `src` attribute.

Comment: You are awesome! Thank you!